# OS X Yosemite not finding Java 8 runtime

Tags: java, macos, osx-yosemite

I installed Java 8 SDK (with update 25 for JRE) from the Oracle Java site using the instructions on this page

```
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html
```

and put the following line in my `~/.bash_profile`

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8"
```

but when I try to compile or run a Java program in Bash I get the following message

```
No Java runtime present, requesting install.
```

and this window

[image]

I ran `/usr/libexec/java_home` to check:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "(null)".
No Java runtime present, try --request to install.
```

But the JRE is in

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current
```

and the JRE location in System Preferences is pointing to

```
/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin
```

I don't know what the problem is here, but `usr/bin/javac` and `/usr/bin/java` are not able to find the correct JVM location in `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current`.

Answer (score 6):

I have encountered the same problem , i think you should install JDK but not JRE

Answer (score 2):

You need to add some backticks:

```
export JAVA_HOME="`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`"
```

The `/usr/libexec/java_home` command outputs the right value for `JAVA_HOME` on its standard output, you need to use backticks to capture that value so you can store it in the variable.

> But the JRE is in /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current

No, it isn't.  The Oracle *JRE* installs itself under `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins`, the Oracle *JDK* installs under `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`.  The binaries under `/usr/bin` and `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands` are stubs that delegate to whichever JDK your `JAVA_HOME` variable points to.

Comment: Yes I did that and resourced the `~/.bash_profile` but it says
    `Last login: Fri Jan  9 13:45:17 on ttys000`
    `Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.8".`
    `No Java runtime present, try --request to install.`

Comment: @kromer did you definitely install the _JDK_, not just the _JRE_?  Do you have anything under `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but it did not work - 

    `Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.8".`
    `No Java runtime present, try --request to install.`

Comment: @kromer then you need to [download the JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and install that - make sure you select the "JDK" button, not the "JRE" one.

Comment: The SDK tools such as `javac` and `java` which I'm trying to use are in `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/`, and the JVM is in `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current`

Comment: @kromer the JVM is _not_ in `/System/Library/Frameworks`, it will be in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` once you've installed it.  The `javac` and `java` in `Version/Current/Commands` are thin stubs that respect `JAVA_HOME` - if you set `JAVA_HOME` to point to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_XX.jdk/Contents/Home` then `Versions/Current/Commands/java` will run Java 8.

Comment: So I guess this means I installed JRE not JDK!!  I dont understand I am sure I did install the SDK (or JDK), but I will have to try it again.  Is there anyway of knowing which one I did install?  I used the brower to download the DMG file from Oracle Java and then used Finder to install it.

Comment: @kromer there are three "download" buttons for Java SE 8u25 on that page I linked to, "JDK", "Server JRE" and "JRE" - you need the top one (JDK).  You don't need to download the JRE separately, it's included as part of the JDK.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved my problem on my mac

1. Check from RStudio if Java_HOME has been setup properly by running `Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME")` in the console. If it returns blank, you need to set it up properly
2. Check whether you have Java SDK installed

   - Open terminal and check if you have Java SDK installed
   - Run the `/usr/libexec/java_home -v`command. This will show you the library where you Java SDK is installed.
3. If you don't have Java SDK installed yet, result from command above is blank, or the version is not up-to-date, download [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and install the latest version.
4. Copy the library shown in step 2. On my mac, it shows:
   `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home`
5. Back on your RStudio console, set the JAVA_HOME
   `Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home")`

After doing the steps above, `h2o.init()` ran without hitch.

Please carefully note @Ian Robert's point on **JRE** vs **JDK** distinction. We need **JDK** to make h2o run.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried several solutions, downloading several sdk but Android Studio didn't recognize them as valid sdks.

Finally, the workaround that worked for me was:

1. Delete Android Studio.app and Android Studio preferences (~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStuido).
2. Rename /usr/libexec/java_home to java_home.bak.
3. Install again Android Stuido.
4. When Android Studio prompts for a valid Java SDK, follow link provided by Android Studio and download that java installation.
5. After installation, push detect button on Android Studio, and run.